# mouse event of infowindow in google map api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any mouse event on infowindow of google map api v3. Like closeclick event.
Actually i m closing the info window after 3 seconds. but i want that if mouse pointer is over infowindow then it should not be close plesae give me example to do it..
Thank you very much.

My Code is written as follow---

```
function generateMarkers(locations, is_paid) 
    { var marker; for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
     {
                var marker;
                for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                    createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]), locations[i][2], locations[i][3], locations[i][4], is_paid);
                }
            }

            function createMarker(pos, name, town, image, is_paid) {
                var infowindow;

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map,  // google.maps.Map 
                    title: name,
                    icon: "images/red.png"

                });
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
                ({
                    content: '<div id="dvContent" onmouseover="clearTime()" onmouseout="clearwindow()"><div style="color:black;float:left"><img src="' + image + '" width="50px" height="50px"/></div><div style="color:black;margin-left:60px">' + name + '<br>Address:' + town + '<br><a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:blue">www.somethingcupid.com</a></div></div>'


                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                    if (is_paid != "True") {

                        document.getElementById("divPopup").style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else {

                        infowindow.open(map, marker);


                    }

                });



                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
                    if (is_paid != "True") {

                        document.getElementById("divPopup").style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else {

                        t = setTimeout(function () { infowindow.close() }, 3000);

                    }

                });
}

                function clearTime() {
                    clearTimeout(t);
                }enter code here

                function clearwindow() {
                    setTimeout(function () { infowindow.close() }, 3000);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only [InfoWindow event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) relevant to mouse activity is `closeclick`.

What you can do is use a `<div>` within the InfoWindow content and use its mouse events. (There will be an inactive border around the active area.)

Comment: this is my content of info window:


content: '<div id="dvContent"><div style="color:black;float:left"><img src="' + image + '" width="50px" height="50px"/></div><div style="color:black;margin-left:60px">' + name + '<br>Address:' + town + '<br></div></div>'

Comment: Jolly good. Add a `mouseover` event to div `dvContent` which runs a function to close the other InfoWindows.

Comment: Actually i m closing the info window after 3 seconds. but i want that if mouse pointer is over infowindow then it should not be close plesae give me example to do it..

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Please update your question with what you have so far.